# The Presocratics - Diels Kranz - Imitations

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Hopefully you are fine!

The standard collection of texts for the Pre-Socratics is that by H. Diels revised by W. Kranz.

This collection divides the chapter concerning every philosopher in two and, sometimes, three parts.

1: Testimonies.
2: Fragments.
3: Imitations.

Regarding the third part, the related [article of IEP](http://www.iep.utm.edu/diels-kr/) says:

> imitations: works which take the author as a model

I am not able to envisage what does it mean, exactly? Definitely, it doesn't mean "how the later philosophers, like Aristotle, comprehended their views" as this lies in the ambit of the first sections, i.e,. testimonies.

1: So, does it mean the views of the later philosophers who adopted and embraced the ideas and views of the Pre-Socratics?

2: And, if an example of any "imitation" is given here, then I am hopeful that it would be more illuminating for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section C collects fake quotations, i.e. quotes which are not genuine.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. I am reading it because it "was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content". Apparently someone thinks more explanation should be added.

Comment: @Jo Wehler  Thank you very much. You have in fact cleared the matter in the most precise way.

Answer (score 1):

The Limitation of Diels-Kranz is not only the numbering method but is the idea of "Presocratics" and then "philosophers". 
Example: if an author in class 3 (imitations) refer for example to Heraclitus, this mean that the the citation is fake. So far so good. But, another example, Democritus  *is* a philosopher but is contemporary to Socrates! So the core of the work of Diels is based on " chronos" (time) or the actual doctrine of author? 
Another example: it seems that Pherecides was the first human person to attribute to Chronus (with kappa, in old  greek, i.e the father of Zeus) the "function" of Time ( X, chi in o. g.). This is not quite common idea! But Pherecides is not include in the presocratics nor as  author chronologically  prior to Socrates nor as philosopher ( but this doesn't mean that I actually include Pherecides in "The Presocratics" )